# Reading NULL Value from SQL that is a BinaryType in c# from a Datarow

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, datarow

I'm trying to read the null value from my SQL.

The column presentationDocBinData is Nullable and it is a NULL.

So i tried reading it this way,

```
presentation.presentationDocBinData = (Byte[])dr["presentationDocBinData"];
```

But according to it, they're unable to read the null value that it receives. It says

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.Byte[]'.

So is there anyway to give it a default value or leave it blank if it is possible?
it works fine with a value in it though.

Answer (score 0):

you have to ask if it is DBNull

```
presentation.presentationDocBinData =dr["presentationDocBinData"]==DBNull.Value?null:(Byte[])dr["presentationDocBinData"];
```